# Can't run any program in

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods, minecraft-computercraft

Probably very dumb problem here. I am trying to run a basic program on my turtle, like a `turtle.forward()`  then `end`. I then save and exit, but when I type the name of the program I want to run, I get this error:

```
bios.lua:14: [string "*nameofmyprogram*"]:2: '<eof>' expected
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Are you sure you named the program correctly *and* typed it in correctly?

Comment: What do you mean by naming it correctly ? I type edit **programname**.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand you're trying to call the following:

```
turtle.forward()
end
```

`end` isn't for function calls, only declarations. Remove the `end` and it should work.